# Export result R data frame into an Excel file

Tags: r

can anyone help me with how to export the result of `comparedf()` from the **arsenal** package to an Excel file?

Here is my script:

```
diff <- diffs(comparedf(mtcars[1:10, ], mtcars[2:11,]))
openxlsx::write.xlsx(diff, "diff.xlsx")
```

> The error message is **Error in is.nan(tmp) : default method not implemented for type 'list'**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`diffs` function returns certain columns of class `'AsIs'` which is of type list.

`unlist` those columns into a vector before writing them to Excel.

```
diff[] <- lapply(diff, function(x) if(class(x) == 'AsIs') unlist(x) else x)
openxlsx::write.xlsx(diff, "diff.xlsx")
```